# How to use zlib.gzipSync(buffer[, options]) for compressing files, and zlib.gunzipSync(buffer[, options]) for decompressing files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, zlib, unzip

**Hi everyone**

I've been going through my head about using zlib in synchronous mode, (Is important to me to be Sync mode)

I have tried and failed multiple times, the node documentation is not entirely clear and use examples are missing

**What I intend to do is:**

A function for
compress a text file "myfile.txt" that contains some data as text as "Some text" and save it as "myfile.txt.gz"

```
function zip(fullPathToFile){
  const zlib= require('zlib');

  //some cool stuff...using:

  zlib.gzipSync(buffer[, options])

}
```

A function for unzip "myfile.txt.gz" into "myfile.txt"

```
function unZip(fullPathToFile){
  const zlib= require('zlib');

  //some cool stuff...using:

  zlib.gunzipSync(buffer[, options])

}
```

all in the same directory

any idea?

thanks for all the reading and helping time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first use `fs.readFileSync` to read the file, then use its return value (a Buffer of the read file) as the first argument to `zlib.gzipSync`. After compressing, I'd use its return value (a Buffer of the data compressed) to write to a file, using `fs.writeFileSync`.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const zlib = require("zlib");

function zip(path) {
    let data = fs.readFileSync(path);
    data = zlib.gzipSync(data);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${path}.gz`, data);
}
```

**For decompression**, replace `zlib.gzipSync` with `zlib.gunzipSync`.